# Having a hard time with a sliding window in perl

Tags: perl, sliding-window

I'm trying to do a sliding window in perl over a large array and I'm having trouble. The details are that I need a window of size 20, then get the average (SMA) of the 20 elements, then print out the SMA numbered 1 to 20 and then start at 1 again.....I started with something like this but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how I'm going to do it.

```
   for($a=0;$a < $#numbers-$window;$a++) {


            $c=1;
            for($b=$a;$b < $a+$window;$b++) {

            }
    }
```

Comment: A good way to clarify a question like this is to give sample input and output.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you're asking, but I think I'd start like this:

```
foreach (0 .. $#numbers - 20) {
  my @window = @numbers[$_ .. $_ + 20];
  # Do something with @window
  ...
}
```

Or this, which doesn't reassign the whole array each time:

```
my @window = @numbers[0 .. 19];

foreach (20 .. $#numbers) {
  # Do something with @window.
  ...

  # Then get the next version of @window ready
  shift @window;
  push @window, $numbers[$_];
}
```

A couple of notes:

1. The C-style `for` loop is almost always the wrong approach.
2. Variables `$a` and `$b` have special meanings to Perl. You shouldn't use them in examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Basically I need to print something like this. 1: SMA 2: SMA 3: SMA .... 20: SMA   and then start again at 1: SMA.  The window size would be 20 but the sequence would count is also 20 .

Comment: You think you're explaining things, but you're really not :-)

Comment: Let me see if I can explain better.... You have a array of 100000 numbers. I know you know what a sliding window is.... So while your'e going through your array with your sliding window, you're getting and printing the SMA of the data in each window. I know how to do that. What I can't wrap my head around is how to print the SMA of each window and numbering it up to a value, lets say 50.

Comment: You're just repeating yourself with more words. Perhaps [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42857380/edit) to add an example. And explain what an "SMA" is.

Comment: @DaveCross I think he means "Simple Moving Average" ... I think the OP is looking for the modulus operator.

Comment: I just figured it out with your help. Thanks for your help. `#!/usr/bin/perl

@data=(1..1000);
$count=1;
foreach (0 .. $#data - 20) {
  my @window = @data[$_ .. $_ + 20];
  $total += $_ for (@window);
  $sma=$total / 20;
  print "$count:$sma ";
  if($count % 20 == 0) { $count=1; print "\n";} else {$count++;}
}
`

Comment: @kernel-trick Stop stuffing stuff in the comments. Edit and update information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Reading between the lines, I am going to guess that you are looking for the modulus operator.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( sum );

use constant WINDOW_SIZE => 20;

my @data = (1 .. 10_000);
my @window = @data[0 .. (WINDOW_SIZE - 1)];
my $n = 1;

for my $i (WINDOW_SIZE .. $#data) {
    my $avg = sum( @window ) / @window;
    printf "%d: %.3f\n", ($n % WINDOW_SIZE) + 1, $avg;
    shift @window;
    push @window, $data[$i];
    ++$n;
}
```

Sample output:

```
1: 10.500       
2: 11.500       
3: 12.500       
4: 13.500       
5: 14.500       
6: 15.500       
7: 16.500       
8: 17.500       
9: 18.500       
10: 19.500      
11: 20.500      
12: 21.500      
13: 22.500      
14: 23.500      
15: 24.500      
16: 25.500      
17: 26.500      
18: 27.500      
19: 28.500      
20: 29.500      
1: 30.500       
2: 31.500       
3: 32.500
...
```